# Exists on a distinct column selection does not work as expected when offset is provided

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Given the following table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE demo (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO demo VALUES (1, 'test');
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (2, 'test');
```

The following queries (which are assumed to be semantically identical - please correct me if I'm wrong):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM demo
WHERE name = 'test';

SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM demo
WHERE name = 'test'
-- actual value is irrelevant as long
-- as it is > number of entries that would result
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0;
```

Both correctly return:

```sql
name
----
test
```

In addition, the query:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM demo
    WHERE name = 'test'
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 0
);
```

also correctly returns `1` (or `t` in PostgreSQL). *However*, the query:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM demo
    WHERE name = 'test'
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 1 -- note the offset: 1 more than what the DISTINCTed query should return
);
```

*also* returns `1` in SQLite and MySQL, but `f` in PostgreSQL. It seems as if the `OFFSET` is applied to the query result in PostgreSQL (as expected), but the `DISTINCT` has precedence in SQLite and MySQL.

AFAIK, the SQL standard defines `LIMIT/OFFSET` to be evaluated last (though I couldn't actually *find* a link to the standard to verify this myself, though every search turns up the same...), meaning that the PostgreSQL behaviour is correct.

Is this a bug that has been fixed in PostgreSQL?

Tested on:

- SQLite 3.36.0
- MySQL 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
- PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

Interestingly, using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` like follows:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT name
    FROM demo
    WHERE name = 'test'
    GROUP BY name
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 1
);
```

correctly returns `0` on SQLite, but it still returns an incorrect result of `1` on MySQL.

Comment: The  `distinct` is pretty useless in combination with an `EXISTS` condition as EXISTS only tests for the _presence_ of a row, not how many rows they are returned. Additionally, the actual column values in the sub-query for an EXISTS condition are completely ignored (you can even write `select 1/0 from ...` which would normally result in an error.

Comment: I agree that `EXISTS` isn't quite the right tool in this case. I'm still surprised at the difference in behaviour between Postgres and SQLite/MySQL here though.

Comment: Well, the query with `OFFSET 1` doesn't return a row, so obviously the EXISTS is false. It seems MySQL returns one row in that case - which seems another weird bug in MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=14ddaf39563036ea961079383a611007 I would say the Postgres result is correct, MySQL and SQLite return a wrong result.

Comment: The SQL standard doesn't define `LIMIT` at all btw. It only defines `fetch first x rows only`

Comment: This question is discussed at [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420281)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, as noted in the comments, this is simply a bug in MySQL and SQLite. I was about to report it on their tracker, but Oracle wants a *lot* of information for me to be able to do that, so I refrained.

The behaviour in PostgreSQL is the expected one and correct.

Comment: Disambiguation: "Oracle" refers to Oracle **** ***the company*** **** and [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL): *"MySQL was owned and sponsored by the Swedish company MySQL AB, which was bought by Sun Microsystems (now Oracle Corporation)."*